# ItextSharp locks all files

Tags: itext

I used itext sharp to merge some pdf. After that, i want to delete them.
However itextsharp doesn't close the file, and File.Delete throws and exception.

This is my code:

```
 Dim mergedPdf As Byte() = Nothing
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using document As New Document()
                Using copy As New PdfCopy(document, ms)
                    document.Open()

                    '_listaPath is a List (of String) with the paths off all pdf to merge
                    For i As Integer = 0 To _listaPDF.Count - 1
                        Dim reader As New PdfReader(_listaPDF(i))
                        ' loop over the pages in that document
                        Dim n As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
                        Dim page As Integer = 0
                        While page < n
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(page)))
                        End While
                    Next

                End Using

            End Using
            mergedPdf = ms.ToArray()

        End Using
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileexplorer.FileName, mergedPdf)
         For Each pdfTMP In _listaPDF
            If File.Exists(pdfTMP) Then
                File.Delete(pdfTMP)
            End If
        Next
        _listaPDF = New List(Of String)
```

Comment: I don't see `document.Close()` anywhere. Please close the document to release the stream. I don't see `reader.Close()` anywhere. Close the reader instances to release the streams.

Comment: "Using" should do it for me. Althought in one of my test, i write: x.dispose() and x.close before every "end using". I update my question whith the code of that test. Same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.

This line

```
Dim reader As New PdfReader(_listaPDF(i))
```

Should be

```
Using reader As New PdfReader(_listaPDF(i))
```

Conclusion, I need more coffee